# sass variables in media query - sass-rails-3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I'm trying to use a variable in a media query  -

```
$break-small: 320px;
$break-large: 1200px;

.profile-pic {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  @media screen and (max-width: $break-small) {
    width: 100px;
    float: none;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: $break-large) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

It says it's now possible [in this article](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32)

It's throwing an error -

```
Invalid CSS after "...nd (max-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$break-small)
```

My gem file  -

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
```

Is sass-rails gem v 3.2.3 behind the sass gem? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Look at your error: "was "$break-mid)" You don't have $break-mid defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry, copied error incorrectly - that's not the issue. Amended question.

Comment: How are you naming those stylesheets files? The extension I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question -

I had a look in my Gemfile.lock, which had the following -

```
sass (3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
```

After that I simply ran 'bundle update sass' which updated sass to the correct version.

Variables in media queries now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this exactly same style in a new rails project with the same gem you are using and it works like a charm. So my guess here is that you are using the `'sass'` extensions for your file, and you should be using `'scss'`.

The syntax between both are incompatible so just change your file names from (for example) `'mystyle.css.sass'` to `'mystyle.css.scss'`

Comment: Afraid not, I've named the files correctly. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == break-small {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $point == break-large {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) { @content; }
  }
}
```

and refer like this:

```
.profile-pic {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  @include breakpoint(break-small) {
    width: 100px;
    float: none;
  }
  @include breakpoint(break-large) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for having a look, but I was being a but silly. I've answered my own question below.